# How do I add a Publishing HTML column to pages?

Tags: 2013, column, publishing, pages

On our site I need to have an extra column on pages where users can enter teaser content. The teaser content is displayed on our homepage.

I've created the teaser column with the 'Multiple lines of text' type. But I need it to be rich text (bold, paragraphs etc). Adding a column of type 'Publishing HTML' doesn't seem to be available.

[image]

[image]

Comment: While selecting multi line text box, if you scroll down you have option to set the editor as Rich Text Editor.

Comment: I don't have this option when adding the 'Multiple lines of text' column to my pages library.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing must be enabled by a site collection administrator for these column types to appear. To enable publishing, go to Settings -> Site Settings.

Under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection features. Scroll down to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and click Activate.

**Create the publishing column**

- From the root of your site collection, click Settings > Site settings.
- Under Web Designer Galleries, click Site columns.
- Click Create.
- Give the column a name.
- In the list of column types, click "Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing."
- In the Existing group box, select Publishing Columns. This step is optional but can be helpful for organizing columns.
- Click OK.

**Add a publishing column to a list or library**

- Navigate to your list or library.
- On the List tab, in the Settings group, click List/Library Settings.
- Under Columns, click Add from existing site columns.
- In the Select site columns from box, click Publishing Columns (or whatever group you chose above).
- In the Available site columns list, click Hyperlink, and then click Add.
- Click OK.

Comment: I need a text box where people can edit text for the teaser content. Make text bold, add paragraphs etc. I don't think this column does that.

Comment: Based on your question I answered on creating Publishing HTML column. Have you tried the outlined steps?

Comment: How can we display only the text of the hyperlink? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/rich-text-column-in-sharepoint-document-library.html) could help you.

for some reason, SharePoint Web UI, can not accept Multi-line fields to be as Rich Text. you can do the trick through SharePoint Designer like detailed in the link above